# How do i get different information in a field based on what i select in a dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add this functionality to my form. when a option from a dropdown menu is selected i want it to input the text field above with the corresponding info. For example:

```
<form name="form1" action="formhandler">

<input type="text" name="typecar">

<select name="BMWCars"> 
<option value="Sedan">Sedan</option> // when this option is chosen put string "5-series" in textfield above
<option value="Convertible">Convertible</option> // when this option is chosen put string "6-series" in textfield above
<option value="Truck">Truck</option> // when this option is chosen put string "X5" in textfield above
<option value="Coupe">Coupe</option> // when this option is chosen put string "3-series" in textfield above
<option value="Hatchback">Hatchback</option> // when this option is chosen put string "5-series GT" in textfield above
</select>

</form>
```

How can this be done with and without having to connect to the to get strings?

Comment: Do you want your text field to contain the value of the selected option, or the text of it? (Obviously they're identical in your case, but in general they are different data.)

Comment: mblase, he has comments after each <option> saying what the value he wants is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is tidier if you make your HTML conform to what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/TgM2W/3/

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="formhandler">
    <input type="text" name="typecar" id="typecar">
    <select name="BMWCars" id="BMWCars"> 
        <option value="">Select one...</option>
        <option value="5-series">Sedan</option>
        <option value="6-series">Convertibles</option>
        <option value="X5">Truck</option>
        <option value="3-series">Coupe</option> 
        <option value="5-series GT">Hatchback</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

JavaScript (without jQuery):

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.forms['form1'].elements['BMWCars'].onchange = function() {
        var opts = this.options;
        document.forms['form1'].elements['typecar'].value = opts[opts.selectedIndex].value;
    };
};
```

or using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#BMWCars').change(function() {
        var opts = $(this)[0].options;
        $('#typecar').val(opts[opts.selectedIndex].value);
    });
});
```

However, if you can't change the HTML, just use an object to store the values and reference that:

```
objBMW = {
    "Sedan":"5-series",
    "Convertible":"6-series",
    "Truck":"X5",
    "Coupe":"3-series",
    "Hatchback":"5-series GT"
};

window.onload = function() {
    document.forms['form1'].elements['BMWCars'].onchange = changer;
};

function changer() {
    var opts = this.options;
    document.forms['form1'].elements['typecar'].value =objBMW[opts[opts.selectedIndex].value];
};
```

Comment: @mblase75 +1 for all the work. I tested the 1st version without jQuery but i'm not seeing the text field being updated like with http://jsfiddle.net/TgM2W/2/. Is it because i put the javascript in de header of the document?

Comment: @jan: yes, it should be added to `window.onload` as a function. I'll update my code.

Comment: @mblase75 Yes it works now. I'm new to javascript and have heard alot about jquery. Is there a benefit in me chosing jquery over the plain javascript and what do i need to implement it with jquery?

Comment: @jan: jQuery is a great timesaver whenever you're making complex changes to a webpage, using AJAX to load external data, or especially when doing any kind of animation. However, if you're just modifying form elements based on other form elements, jQuery doesn't improve things much. jQuery *is* JavaScript, but it is a REALLY different way of thinking about JavaScript, and I for one would strongly recommend a solid understanding of "plain" JavaScript first.

Comment: @mblase75 why is the solution with the objects giving a undefined message?

Comment: @jan: probably because it was designed to be used with your original HTML, not my modified HTML.  http://jsfiddle.net/TgM2W/8/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3876/discussion-between-jan-and-mblase75)

Comment: @mblase75 Yeah i figured out later thanks. I was thinking how can i do the same thing above but then, with separate data that is stored as an variable.Not as : <option value="3-series"> but as 'var option3series = '3series' ' because i want the dropdownlist to remain storing the cartype:truck,sedan, coupe etc in database?

Comment: You can store data in an attribute like `data-textstr="3series"` and access it using the `.data()` method in jQuery, but that won't work with "classic" JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Jan. This is what you have to do:

1. Add identifier to all your referenced items in the HTML.
2. Write an small Javascript code to detect changes in the dropdown and update the textfield accordly.

```
<form name="form1" action="formhandler">

<input type="text" name="typecar" id="typecar" />

<select name="BMWCars" id="dropdown"> 
<option value="5-series">Sedan</option>
<option value="6-series">Convertible</option>
<option value="X5">Truck</option>
<option value="3-series">Coupe</option>
<option value="5-series GT">Hatchback</option>
</select>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var dropdown = document.getElementById( 'dropdown' );
dropdown.onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById( 'typecar' ).value = dropdown.value;
};
</script>
```

Comment: +1 for your input I've tested it and it works! I was thinking how can i do the same thing above but then, with separate data that is stored as an variable.Not as : `<option value="3-series">` but as 'var option3series = '3series' ' because i want the dropdownlist to remain storing the cartype:truck,sedan, coupe etc in database?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to do it in jQuery (or javascript).

```
$("option").change(function() {
     var value;  

    //Do some logic to get the value you want to put in the textbox

    $("input[name='typecar']").val(value);
});
```

Depending on the complexity of your site, there's a couple different ways you can grab the value to put in your textbox.  If it will only ever be those 5 options, I would suggest a switch...case.  Like this:

```
$("option".change(function() {
    var value;

    switch($(this).val()) {
          case "Sedan":
               value = "5-series";
               break;

          case "Convertible":
               value = "6-series";
               break;

          case "Truck":
               value = "X5";
               break;

          case "Coupe":
               value = "3-series";
               break;

          case "Hatchback":
               value = "5-series GT";
               break;
     }

    $("input[name='typecar']").val(value);

});
```

Comment: There is no good reason at all that he should HAVE to do it in jQuery.

Comment: Good point.  It is, however, easier to do it in jQuery.  And he has jQuery as a tag.  I will edit my post, though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('select').change(function() {
     var value = $(this).val();
        $("#typecar").val(value);
});
```

Should do it. Add an ID of typecar to your input field first however.